# tesselation evaluation shader linking error

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am trying to make a tesselation shader but I am getting an error during the linking of the tesselation evaluation shader:

geometry shaders require #extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4

this is my shader :

```
#version 400 core

layout (triangles, equal_spacing, cw) in;

void main(void){ 

gl_Position=(gl_TessCoord.x*gl_in[0].gl_Position) +
         (gl_TessCoord.y*gl_in[1].gl_Position)+
        ( gl_TessCoord.z*gl_in[2].gl_Position);

}
```

and this is how I implement it :

```
    Shader::Shader(const GLchar* vertexPath, const GLchar* fragmentPath,                     const GLchar* tessCPath, const GLchar* tessEPath)
{
// 1. Retrieve the vertex/fragment source code from filePath
string vertexCode;
string fragmentCode;
string tessConCode;
string tessEvalCode;
try
{
    // Open files
    ifstream vShaderFile(vertexPath);
    ifstream fShaderFile(fragmentPath);
    ifstream tcShaderFile(tessCPath);
    ifstream teShaderFile(tessEPath);

    stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream, tcShaderStream, teShaderStream;
    // Read file's buffer contents into streams
    vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
    fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();
    tcShaderStream << tcShaderFile.rdbuf();
    teShaderStream << teShaderStream.rdbuf();

    // close file handlers
    vShaderFile.close();
    fShaderFile.close();
    tcShaderFile.close();
    teShaderFile.close();

    // Convert stream into string
    vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
    fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
    tessConCode = tcShaderStream.str();
    tessEvalCode = teShaderStream.str();
}
catch (exception e)
{
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << endl;
}

const GLchar* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
const GLchar * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
const GLchar* tcShaderCode = tessConCode.c_str();
const GLchar* teShaderCode = tessEvalCode.c_str();

// 2. Compile shaders
GLuint vertex, fragment, tessControl, tessEval;
GLint success;
GLchar infoLog[512];

// Vertex Shader
vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertex);
// Print compile errors if any
glGetShaderiv(vertex, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
}

// Fragment Shader
fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragment);
// Print compile errors if any
glGetShaderiv(fragment, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(fragment, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
}

// tesselation control Shader
tessControl = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_CONTROL_SHADER);
glShaderSource(tessControl, 1, &tcShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(tessControl);
// Print compile errors if any
glGetShaderiv(tessControl, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(tessControl, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::TESSCONTROL::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
}

// tesselation eval Shader
tessEval = glCreateShader(GL_TESS_EVALUATION_SHADER);
glShaderSource(tessEval, 1, &teShaderCode, NULL);
glCompileShader(tessEval);
// Print compile errors if any
glGetShaderiv(tessEval, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(tessEval, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::TESSEVAL::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
}

// Shader Program
this->Program = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(this->Program, vertex);
glAttachShader(this->Program, tessControl);
glAttachShader(this->Program, fragment);
glAttachShader(this->Program, tessEval);
glLinkProgram(this->Program);
// Print linking errors if any
glGetProgramiv(this->Program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetProgramInfoLog(this->Program, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n" << infoLog << endl;
}
// Delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
glDeleteShader(vertex);
glDeleteShader(fragment);
glDeleteShader(tessControl);
glDeleteShader(tessEval);
```

}

I have noticed that I can put anything in as the tesselation evaluation shader path and still get the same error, so it probably means it can't find the file. But I have checked many times that the name of the file and the name I use in my program are the same. I am using opengl 4.1. Does anyone have an idea what the problem may be?

Comment: How do you know it's the tessellation evaluation shader that's causing the problem? You're linking 4 source files, any one of them could be mistakenly interpreted as a geometry shader. In fact, it'd be more likely for a control shader to be misinterpreted as a geometry shader.

Comment: the opengl log while linking says so :

Answer (score 0):

change the start of your shader to add the required extension:

`#version 400 core`

`#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : enable`